# What does a sub-path mean in the context of import statements?

Tags: javascript, npm, import, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have a statement like this:

```
import * as bar from 'foo/bar';
```

I have a few questions:

- What does the `/bar` bit mean?
- Is there a sepcific (google-able) term for this?
- Does this provide efficiency gains (reducing module bloat)?
- How can I bundle a common-js module (ideally with Rollup) on NPM and support this syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Breaking it down:

Firstly to provide context to your first and second question, let's go a bit further and break down all the parts of that statement:

> `import * as quux from 'foo/bar';`

*Note: The first `bar` instance in your example has been intentionally changed to `quux` to disambiguate the following points.*

1. Collectively it is referred to as an ***Import Statement***, or more specifically; an ***Import Declaration*** as defined in the [ECMA-262 Imports Syntax Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports).
2. The `import` part is referred to as the ***Import Keyword***.
3. The `* as quux` part is referred to as a ***NameSpace Import***.

   - The asterisk `*` indicates that all exported bindings in `bar` will be imported to a newly created namespace object called `quux`. The resultant effect is that the `quux` object will hold all the exported members from `bar`.
   - The `quux` part of that is referred to as the ***Imported Binding*** and, as previously mentioned, it's used as the name for the newly created namespace object.
4. The `from 'foo/bar'` part is referred to as the ***From Clause***.

   - The `foo/bar` part is a *String Literal* and is referred to as the ***Module Specifier***... it's simply a filepath.

---

#### Answers to your specific questions:

1. > What does the `/bar` bit mean?

   It's part of the ***Module Specifier*** which is part of the ***From Clause***. It is simply a reference to the name of the file whose exported member(s) will be imported from. In this example its exported member(s) will be imported into a new namespace object called `quux`.

   With regards to what is that actual *"part"* called; ECMA-262 doesn't provide a specific reference/name for it, however, I refer to that part as the *filename*; *(i.e. the filename in the filepath of the module to import)*.

   As far as I know, `/bar` may or may not need to include a file extension (i.e. `/bar.js`). Again there's nothing in the *ECMA-262 Imports Syntax* that enforces this. ECMAScript only defines the syntax for modules and not the specific mechanism(s) for loading them. So the requirement for with or without a `.js` suffix may vary per implementation. For example:

   - In Apple's latest Safari browser built upon WebKit which runs on iOS the inclusion of the `.js` suffix is necessary.
   - In [Modules docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_modules) for Node v8.10.0 they do include the `.js` file extension for imported files in their examples. *Note: As ES6 Modules currently have a [Stability Index 2](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/documentation.html#documentation_stability_index) this could change.*
2. > Is there a specific (google-able) term for this?

   Not per se, as ECMA hasn't named it specifically. You could try googling some of the terminology/nomenclature that I've previously mentioned.
3. > Does this provide efficiency gains (reducing module bloat)?

   I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by *"module bloat"*. However, If you mean will it result in less modules in application code? I think not, it's more likely result in an increased usage of modules.

   Efficiency gains will be had from there being *native* ES6 Module support. Native support by it's very nature can bring speed/performance increases. Other benefits of ES6 Modules are:

   - ES6 Modules are statically analyzable which allows dead/unused code elimination via a process named *Tree Shaking*. More info [here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup#tree-shaking) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking) . So, if that's what you mean by the term "module bloat" - then yes; unused/dead code will be removed by tools that perform *Tree Shaking*.

     **Caveat**; I'm not 100% certain whether tools that perform *Tree Shaking* are capable of removing dead code when using the wildcard/asterisk (`*`) in a *NameSpace Import*. It *MAY* be necessary to import specific member(s) that you'll use instead, i.e.

     ```js
       import { foo, bar, quux } from './foo/bar.js';
     ```
   - It's an official ECMAScript standard.
   - The example that you gave included a *NameSpace Import*, so there's another benefit - it will help to avoid namespace collisions.
   - More benefits are mentioned [here](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#benefits-of-ecmascript-6-modules).
4. > How can I bundle a common-js module (ideally with Rollup) on NPM and support this syntax?

   [Rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup) works with a plugin named [@rollup/plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs) which will convert CommonJS modules to ES6, so they can be included in a Rollup bundle.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer. I asked about `import *` specifically here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417236/is-import-as-less-efficient-than-specific-named-imports

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that link - Although not conclusive it seems _(from the answers to that post)_ that some _"Tree Shakers"_ are able to detect and remove dead code when using a _NameSpace Import_. That's useful to know!

Comment: Clarification regarding NPM: if I ship an extra file `bar.js` in the NPM module `foo`, will that be picked up by `import 'foo/bar.js';` ?