# Is "import * as" less efficient than specific named imports?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

Suppose I have a module `foo` like this:

```
export const f = x => x + 1;

export const g = x => x * 2;
```

I can use this module like this:

```
import { f, g } from 'foo';

console.log(f(g(2)));
```

Or like this:

```
import * as foo from 'foo';

console.log(foo.f(foo.g(2)));
```

I prefer the second way because it prevents name collisions between modules.

However, is `import *` less efficient? Does it prevent bundlers (such as Rollup and Webpack)  from spotting unused imports and removing them?

Comment: This depends on the implementation. Up-to-date Webpack versions optimize * imports, not sure about Rollup.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the dupe. I renamed that question to hopefully make it easier for people to find.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks. I could only find it because I knew that I had answered it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify imports as `import { f, g } from 'foo';` you guarantee better performance in terms of speed in compilation and bundle size as you will be getting only the dependencies you need.

Notes: as loganfsmyth pointed out, some recent compiler/bundle are able to reference what actually is being used only, this IMO is an additional step which could cost some compilation time (although I did not have time to benchmark this assumption).

Comment: Most module bundlers are also able to look at the namespace object to see what references are actually used, so I don't think this is accurate?

Comment: Please do a benchmark. I'm certain the difference is not noticeable.

Comment: @Bergi good point +1, I will also add that it depends my the number of exports and size of the project.

Answer (score 1):

import * is less efficient in that you are using more memory to pull the entire library as opposed to just the specific methods that you actually need

Comment: That depends entirely on the module implementation. Webpack is perfectly able to optimize the main cases of `import * as` too.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack at least (not sure about Rollup), is perfectly able to see that `foo.f` is a reference to the `f` exported name, so your two examples will behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

For most bundlers this does not matter since everything has to be included, 'cause

```
export const g = (() => {
    console.log("Side effects!");

    return x => x * 2;
})();
```